# jQuery animate() width duration

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-animate

I'm trying to animate the width of a progress bar but no matter what duration I use the animation takes the same time. In Chrome it just delays. In Firefox the animation is slow in the beginning and faster in the en. I don't know why this is happening.

```js
var $progressBar = $(".progress-bar")
$progressBar.animate({
  width: $progressBar.text()
}, 5000);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:0%">60%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because by default Bootstrap applies a `transition: width` rule on the CSS for the `.progress-bar` element. This is interfering with the jQuery logic that animates the width of the bar, so you need to override that CSS rule to remove it, like this:

```js
var $progressBar = $(".progress-bar");
$progressBar.animate({
  width: $progressBar.text()
}, 5000);
```

```css
div .progress-bar {
  transition: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:0%">60%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```